# Problem with implementation of a drag'n'drop component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to build a dnd component that will keep attached child component from another parent when the last gets removed

There are several components already implemented. The structure basically goes like that:

```
(simplified)

<Droppable/> // takes children via dnd and does stuff on them
<Pagination/> // provides subsets of data on a client-side, sets navigation
<List> // renders items
  <Draggable> //takes only props.children
    ...
    <Item/> might be processed in <Droppable/>
    ...
  <Draggable/>
<List/>
```

/-----------------------------------------------------------------------/

```
import React from "react";

const Droppable = props => {
  const drop = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = e.dataTransfer.getData("transfer");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); 
  };

  const allowDrop = e => {
   e.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <div onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop} className="droppable">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Droppable;
```

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
import React from "react";

const Draggable = props => {
  const drag = e => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("transfer", e.target.id);
  };

  const preventDrop = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  return (
    <div
      id={props.id}
      draggable="true"
      onDragStart={drag}
      onDragOver={preventDrop}
    >
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Draggable;
```

e.target.appendChild(data) Works as expected until List gets a new subset of data and renders it, then two problems arise:

1. React wants to dismount appended component from Droppable
2. It fails and crashes with a "DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node." error

e.target.appendChild(document.importNode(document.getElementById(data), true)) works with no errors but makes a copy and doesn't remove child from the List

is there any straightforward way of solving this task in reactjs?